# upload same artifact to hawkbit

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit

We have just updated to latest version of hawkbit. Before we for testing uploaded the same artifact on different softwaremodules.
After update to latest version that is no longer possible. We get 409 error. Can't find information about in the API documentation or in the release notes.
Is this how it is supposed to be?

Created two different software modules. Added artifact 1 to software 1 and then tried to add artifact 1 to software 2.

using rest/v1/softwaremodules/[softwaremoduleId]/artifacts

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to upload an artifact with the same hashes to HawkBit, as it will clash with the file name.

Artifacts are not a top-level collection, so they are always associated with a specific software module. At present it is not possible to have the exact same binary file listed on two software modules. You will have to be creative and think of a way to crate a different binary.